# Setting Map Pin colour dynamically for iOS

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I parse an xml that contains the string 0 ,1 and 2.

//For reference
0 = Green
1 = Red
2 = Purple

I have a class that confirms to the MKAnnotaion that contains the below variables that are properties.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
NSString            *title;
NSString            *subtitle;
MKPinAnnotationColor pinColor;
```

This class is named MyAnnotation

Now in the viewDidLoad of the map view I run a for loop to iterate over the parsed data
like the below (locationArray holds this data and I pull out all the info just fine.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < locationArray.count; i++) {
    myAnnotation =[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];

    NSString *thePointName = [[locationArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlName];
    NSString *theAddress = [[locationArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlAddress];

    NSString *latString = [[locationArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlLat];
    NSString *lonString = [[locationArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlLon];
```

//This is the string that pulls out the mentioned 0, 1 or 2 strings which represent the colour of the pins poinType is retained as a string

```
    pointType = [[locationArray objectAtIndex:i]xmlType];

    double theLatitude = [latString doubleValue];
    double theLongtitude = [lonString doubleValue];

    userLocation.latitude=theLatitude;
    userLocation.longitude=theLongtitude;

    myAnnotation.coordinate=userLocation;
    myAnnotation.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", thePointName];
    myAnnotation.subtitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", theAddress];

    //I log that the points are actually giving either of the colors and if so set MyAnnotation class to the pincolor 

    NSLog(@"Points Color %@", pointType);
    if ([pointType isEqualToString:@"0"]){
        myAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    }else if ([pointType isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        myAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    }else if ([pointType isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        myAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    }

    [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];

    }
```

Now in the MKAnnotationView view i do the below

```
  - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id     <MKAnnotation>)annotation

 {

// if it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

// try to dequeue an existing pin view first
static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                  initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
pinView.canShowCallout=YES;

    //set pin color to the correct colour
    if (myAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen) {
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    }

    else if (myAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed) {
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

     }

    else if (myAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple){
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    }



    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rightButton addTarget:self
                action:@selector(showDetails:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;


    UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"Profile.png"]];
pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;

return pinView;
  }
```

I have also tried in the above method however it is not setting the pin colours. Everything else is fine!

```
    //set pin color to the correct colour
    if (pointType isEqualToString:@"0") {
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    }

    else if (pointType isEqualToString:@"1") {
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

    }

    else if (pointType isEqualToString:@"2"){
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code in `viewForAnnotation`:

```
if (myAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen) {
```

will not work for two reasons:

1. It is using a single equals sign which is for assignment -- not for checking equality.  It needs to use two equal signs to check for equality.  However, this doesn't fix the main issue which is reason #2...
2. The code is checking the value of `myAnnotation` which is a variable set outside this delegate method.  There is *no guarantee* that the delegate method will be called in sync with the for-loop in which `myAnnotation` is set.  Do not assume that `viewForAnnotation` will be called right after you call `addAnnotation`.  It is even possible for the delegate method to be called multiple times for the same annotation if the map view needs to display the annotation again after a zoom or pan.

Instead, you must use the `annotation` parameter that is passed to the delegate method.  This is a reference to the annotation the map view wants a view for in the current call of the delegate method.

Since the `annotation` parameter is typed generically as `id<MKAnnotation>`, you'll first have to cast it to your custom class and then you can access any custom properties:

```
//first make sure this annotation is our custom class before casting it...
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
{
    MyAnnotation *currentAnn = (MyAnnotation *)annotation;

    if (currentAnn.pinColor == MKPinAnnotationColorGreen) {
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    }

    else if (currentAnn.pinColor == MKPinAnnotationColorRed) {
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

    }

    else if (currentAnn.pinColor == MKPinAnnotationColorPurple) {
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    }
}
```

or even simpler:

```
//first make sure this annotation is our custom class before casting it...
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
{
    MyAnnotation *currentAnn = (MyAnnotation *)annotation;        
    pinView.pinColor = currentAnn.pinColor;
}
```

(Unrelated, but why is the code setting the title of `rightButton` even though it won't be visible?)

Comment: Firstly I am a dufus :-) yes it was late I should have used == and second I am really stupid I should have know to used this if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
{
    MyAnnotation *currentAnn = (MyAnnotation *)annotation; to many late nights catching up with me so thanks very much for your time!