# How to display MKPinAnnotationView on MKMapview in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, annotations, maps

I'm trying to implement a customised annotation view onto a pin in MKMapView. Another user has given me this function to use to generate a customised MKPinAnnotationView. https://stackoverflow.com/users/3845091/zisoft

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
if annotation is PinAnnotation {
    let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myPin")

    pinAnnotationView.pinColor = .Purple
    pinAnnotationView.draggable = true
    pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
    pinAnnotationView.animatesDrop = true

    let deleteButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    deleteButton.frame.size.width = 44
    deleteButton.frame.size.height = 44
    deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    deleteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "trash"), forState: .Normal)

    pinAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = deleteButton

    return pinAnnotationView
}

return nil
```

}

And I would pass the function the parameters of the map I want it on and the annotation I want to customise. i.e. `mapView(myMap, viewForAnnotation: point)`

This is all well and good and makes sense, however, when I try to add the MKPinAnnotationView to the map using 
`map.addAnnotation(mapView(myMap, viewForAnnotation: point))` 
it errors saying that the data type is not valid. Does anybody know how to physically render the pin on the map with the customised view?

A simple solution is always best.

Thanks!

Comment: May this helps you in better way http://www.raywenderlich.com/87008/overlay-views-mapkit-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, you say about the `viewForAnnotation` method:

> And I would pass the function the parameters of the map I want it on
>   and the annotation I want to customise. i.e. mapView(myMap,
>   viewForAnnotation: point)

No, this is wrong.

**You** would not pass the function the parameters, etc.

That `viewForAnnotation` method is a **delegate** method you implement but is **not** called directly by you.

The **map view** (`MKMapView`) will call it and pass the function the parameters, etc.

The `viewForAnnotation` delegate method is where you can provide a custom **view** for the given annotation **model** object.

To make sure the map view calls your delegate methods, you must either:

- Make sure the map view's `delegate` outlet is connected to its view controller in the storyboard, or
- In code, usually in `viewDidLoad`, do `mapView.delegate = self`.

---

When you call `addAnnotation`, you pass it the annotation **model** object (eg. an `MKPointAnnotation` or anything that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol).

So this line:

```
map.addAnnotation(mapView(myMap, viewForAnnotation: point))
```

should be something like:

```
map.addAnnotation(point)
```

An `MKPinAnnotationView` object (and anything that subclasses `MKAnnotationView`) is the **view** for some annotation **model** object -- they are not the same things.

---

These questions and topics have been covered already many times in the iOS and MapKit documentation, on SO and on tutorials available elsewhere.

Here are just a couple of related questions on SO that you may find useful:

- [Stuck on using MKPinAnnotationView() within Swift and MapKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523702/stuck-on-using-mkpinannotationview-within-swift-and-mapkit)
- [viewForAnnotation confusion and customizing the pinColor iteratively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613511/viewforannotation-confusion-and-customizing-the-pincolor-iteratively)

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem and makes this far clearer.