# multiple custom pin annotation images

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation, mkannotationview

How do u assign different reuse identifiers to show multiple images using MKAnnotationView? I am getting my response via my parse backend server, in which every pin represents a type of location whose pin is custom image. Only swift code please.

Comment: Hey, Let me know whether this question helped you or not ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613511/viewforannotation-confusion-and-customizing-the-pincolor-iteratively

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly... Thank You very much :-)